# Why is mdsvex causing a vite dev server error?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to get mdsvex up and running with a new SvelteKit project to handle markdown and it seems to be causing some kind of import error for Vite?

To illustrate the issue I've gone ahead and initialized a SvelteKit project with `npm create svelte@latest ./`, followed by `npm i -D mdsvex`. I left my routes folder empty except for the base `+page.svelte` file Sveltekit creates by default.

The mdsvex docs are a little bit unclear on correct setup within the `svelte.config.js` file. But I did the following.

svelte.config.js

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { mdsvex } from "mdsvex"

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    extensions: [".svx"], I ADDED THIS LINE
    preprocess: [
        vitePreprocess(),
        mdsvex({ // AND THIS ONE
            extensions: [".svx"] // AND THIS ONE TOO
        }),
    ],

    kit: {
        // adapter-auto only supports some environments, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-auto for a list.
        // If your environment is not supported or you settled on a specific environment, switch out the adapter.
        // See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters for more information about adapters.
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;
```

this is essentially the stock boiler plate config created by SvelteKit. As far as I'm aware this is correct usage of mdsvex. The only thing I changed was my `svelte.config.js`.

when I run `npm run dev` and navigate to the site on localhost, I'm greeted with this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is also mandatory to have `.svelte` in the extensions array:

```js
const config = {
  extensions: ['.svelte', '.svx'],
  ...
}
```